# How get the entire document first, then make the changes and save the entire document

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I am new to cosmos db and  creating a project base on cosmos db .I created the basic crud operation. Now the problem one is user has more work ,work may have different category and in each category have different work.

Addwork code example :

```
public async Task < Catalog > AddAsync(Guid id,
    user order) {
    var requestOptions =
        new RequestOptions {
            PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(order.Id.ToString())
        };

    catalogDocument = await _cosmosClient.UpsertDocumentAsync(
        UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(
            _azureCosmosDbOptions.Value.DatabaseId, "list"), order, requestOptions);

    return (user)((dynamic) catalogDocument.Resource);
}
```

Json body :

```
 "id": "8000003c-0001-fb00-b63f-84710c7967aa",

    "work": {

      "category": [
        {

          "subcategory": [
            {
               "work" :{
                    "id":"22",
                   "dec":"one work"
                }
```

json body input:

```
 "id": "8000003c-0001-fb00-b63f-84710c7967aa",

    "work": {

      "category": [
        {

          "subcategory": [
            {
               "work" :{
                    "id":"23",
                   "dec":"two work"
                }
```

actual output:

```
 "id": "8000003c-0001-fb00-b63f-84710c7967aa",

    "work": {

      "category": [
        {

          "subcategory": [
            {
               "work" :{
                    "id":"23",
                   "dec":"two work"
                }
```

But the expected output:

```
 "id": "8000003c-0001-fb00-b63f-84710c7967aa",

    "work": {

      "category": [
        {

          "subcategory": [
            {
               "work" :{
                    "id":"22",
                   "dec":"one work"
                },
                "work" :{
                    "id":"23",
                   "dec":"two work"
                }
```

I need to update with out rewrite my database.for example work1 already exit ,after enter work2 ,my list must have two work data set .Please give me some ideas 
thank you

Comment: Not sure I understand your question or specific challenge. But... any update to an existing document is actually a *replace* of that document. So, if it exists already, you need to read it, modify it, and replace it (which effectively overwrites your original document). Please edit your question to be more clear. Ideally, include expected input/output, actual input/output, errors, etc.

Comment: sir i added . please tell me how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly , you are looking for partial update. Azure cosmos db doesn't support partial updates now. Though you can use stored procedure to update the entire document.

```
function updateSproc(id, update) {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();
    var collectionLink = collection.getSelfLink();
    var response = getContext().getResponse();

    tryQueryAndUpdate();

    function tryQueryAndUpdate(continuation) {
        var query = {query: "select * from root r where r.id = @id", parameters: [{name: "@id", value: id}]};
        var requestOptions = {continuation: continuation};

        var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(collectionLink, query, requestOptions, function (err, documents, responseOptions) {
            if (err) throw err;

            if (documents.length > 0) {
                tryUpdate(documents[0]);
            } else {
                throw new Error("Document not found.");
            }
        });
    }

function tryUpdate(document) {
    var requestOptions = {etag: document._etag};

    var fields, i;

    fields = Object.keys(update);
    for (i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
       document[fields[i]] = update[fields[i]];
    }

    var isAccepted = collection.replaceDocument(document._self, document, requestOptions, function (err, updatedDocument, responseOptions) {
        if (err) throw err;
        response.setBody(updatedDocument);
    });
}
```

Hope it helps.